# Twitter Rest Api call limitations (using node package twit) get tweets for 1000+ users in a single go

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm, twitter-oauth

I'm getting tweets from twitter User_timeline for multiple user accounts using NPM twit.

Number of accounts is 1000 +.

1. How long one Authentication lasts(new access tokens and same consumer key).
2. what is the best way to prevent limits.e.g how to get user_timeline for all 1000 users.
3. Is it possible to authenticate as many users with different access tokens but with same consumer key in 15-min window.
4. Is there any limitation on IP too ?

Comment: Whatever, in your case, in rest, you'll hit the request limit very fast. Have you considered the streaming API ?

Comment: streaming api is not my solution one can only have few number of persistent streams for different accounts. But i have large number of user accounts.

Comment: In case i use streaming Api and make some accoints wait . then i will lose data comming in that time window. I need all time line activity. I was using streaming Api first then i came to know about the limitation.

Comment: You could open a persistent stream, following all your accounts (I don't know if the api has a limit but the doc doesn't talk about it : https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow ) - but you'll have to leave it open 24/7, not to miss a tweet, I agree.

Comment: Yup, its not in Doc i saw that in offical twitter form. Is it possible to open single stream for multiple user accouts ? if yes it will work for me.

Comment: var stream = T.stream('user', {})
 
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  //... 
})

Comment: In fact you won't open a stream for "user accounts", you'll open a stream that will hand you in real time only the tweets from the users of the ids you specified (semantics I agree). I've worked with Twitter streams before, it works well (I've never handed it thousands of user ids though - this, you'll have to check)

Comment: this is what i was using

Comment: Thanks i will check it out hope it will work. If you have some example kindly share with me.

Comment: Don't use user streams, use : T.stream('statuses/filter', {}) , this way you'll be able to follow all your users - Providing example of code in lib : https://github.com/topheman/twitter-stream-channels/blob/master/lib/StreamChannels.js#L31 - example in use : http://topheman-datavisual.herokuapp.com/ - but you'll use directly twitt (you won't need my lib)

Comment: #follow  only returns tweets created by user and reply to user created tweets.  I also want direct tweets mentioning the user (e.g. "@mark hi you there"). Like Rest Api mention_timeline returns. :/

Comment: Is it possible to make a new twitter Application using some Api for an account.
If i have access tokens of that account ?